# Is there a way to tell Vim not to remove indent that was automatically added when I moving the cursor?

Tags: vim, indentation, auto-indent

For example: I write a line and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Then if auto indent turn on cursor moves to the next line with the same indent like current line. If then I move the cursor sonewhere else and then return to this place there will be no indent. But I want to save indent that was added automatically.

Comment: Do you *really* want your file to be littered with trailing white space?

Comment: It will be not trailing because I need this indent for writing text after it. For example when I need copy-paste a word from some location to the beginning of the new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert any text on the line, even if you delete it, Vim will keep the indent. So just type <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> on the new line to keep the indent after leaving it. Or do it automatically with a mapping:

```
inoremap <Enter> <Enter>x<BS>
```